# ExpandabelListView not showing any data

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have implemented a custom ExpandableListView but it is not showing any data.

here is my layout.

**activity_cust_mainlist.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_cust_salesRep"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="94dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="sales man"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_cust_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_cust_salesRep"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Lista de Clientes"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_cust_header"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:weightSum="11" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_custtime"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Horario"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_custid"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Cod"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_custname"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Nombre"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/eLV_customers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lin" >
    </ExpandableListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_cust_group_list.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:weightSum="11">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_custList_Time"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Horario"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_custList_id"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Cod"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_custList_Name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Nombre"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_cust_child_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_clildList_refe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="REFE"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**The Actual Code: CustomerActivity**

```
  package com.dhiraj.mpos;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class CustomerActivity extends Activity {

        private ArrayList<String> parentItems;
        private ArrayList<Object> childItems;

        ExpandableListView listView;
        ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_cust_temp);

            parentItems = new ArrayList<String>();
            childItems = new ArrayList<Object>();
            setGroupParents();
            setChildData();

            listView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.eLV_customers);
            listAdapter = new MyCustomExpandableAdapter(parentItems, childItems);

            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            Log.i("dhiraj", "adapter set");

        }

        private class MyCustomExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
            ArrayList<String> parent,child;
            ArrayList<Object> children;

            MyCustomExpandableAdapter(ArrayList<String> parents,
                    ArrayList<Object> childern) {
                this.parent = parents;
                this.children = childern;           
                Log.i("dhiraj", " constructor");
            }

            @Override
            public Object getChild(int arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long getChildId(int arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                    boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                child=(ArrayList<String>)children.get(groupPosition);

                Log.i("dhiraj", "getChildView : " + child.toString());

                if (convertView == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) CustomerActivity.this
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_cust_child_list, null);
                }

                TextView tv1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_clildList_refe);
                tv1.setText(child.get(childPosition));

                return convertView;
            }

            @Override
            public int getChildrenCount(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getGroup(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public int getGroupCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public long getGroupId(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                    View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                Log.i("dhiraj", "groupView");


                if (convertView == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) CustomerActivity.this
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_cust_group_list, null);

                }

                TextView tv_time = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_custList_Time);
                TextView tv_id = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_custList_id);
                TextView tv_name = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_custList_Name);

                tv_name.setText(this.parent.get(groupPosition));

                return convertView;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasStableIds() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void setGroupParents() {
            parentItems.add("Fruits");
            parentItems.add("Flowers");
            parentItems.add("Animals");
            parentItems.add("Birds");
            Log.i("dhiraj", "group items set");
        }

        // method to set child data of each parent
        public void setChildData() {

            // Add Child Items for Fruits
            ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
            child.add("Apple");
            child.add("Mango");
            child.add("Banana");
            child.add("Orange");

            childItems.add(child);

            // Add Child Items for Flowers
            child = new ArrayList<String>();
            child.add("Rose");
            child.add("Lotus");
            child.add("Jasmine");
            child.add("Lily");

            childItems.add(child);

            // Add Child Items for Animals
            child = new ArrayList<String>();
            child.add("Lion");
            child.add("Tiger");
            child.add("Horse");
            child.add("Elephant");

            childItems.add(child);

            // Add Child Items for Birds
            child = new ArrayList<String>();
            child.add("Parrot");
            child.add("Sparrow");
            child.add("Peacock");
            child.add("Pigeon");

            childItems.add(child);

            Log.i("dhiraj", "child items set");

        }
    }
```

Comment: Now I am getting other error. http://wikisend.com/download/847830/log.txt.  The error is on line `TextView tv_time = (TextView) convertView
     .findViewById(R.id.tv_custList_Time);`

Comment: Got it. I hadnt initialised the convertView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

notice that in your adapter, the overridden methods return 0, null..
they should actually return the items and the items count, if you'll debug the app, you'll see that the adapter's count is always 0, so even though you've done all the wiring from the activity, and added all the group and child items, you'll see nothing.

try changing getGroupCount() to return groupItems.size() and the same for getChildCount()

let us know if it fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

Your getChildrenCount is returning 0 and also your getGroupCount is returning 0.

You need to modify it to return the correct count for each group.